# Why is my reference list not alphabetically ordered?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

[image]My bibliography.bib is not sorted by alphabetically and I don't understand why. I want it to be alphabetical and I am even using IEEEtran style. 
This is my codes,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[redeflists]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{units}
 \usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\raggedright
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}


\end{document}
```

And this is my .bib file,

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}

@article{tt3,
author = {C. J. Neil},
title = {The Lagrange Points},
journal = {National Aeronautics and Space Administration},
note = {{\url{https://wmap.gsfc.nasa.gov/mission/observatory_l2.html}} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-09]}},
year = {2012},
}

@article{tt1,
author = {P. Katie},
title = {How our solar system was born},
journal = {Nationalencyklopedin},
note = {{https://www.nhm.ac.uk/discover/how-our-solar-system-was-born.html} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-09]}},
year = {u.å},
} nuuuuu GICK DEEET

@article{tt2,
author = {{Solar System Exploration}},
title = {Vårt solsystem},
journal = {Solar System Exploration},
note = {{https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/solar-system/our-solar-system/in-depth/} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-05]}},
year = {2019},
}

@article{tt4,
author = {W. Flint},
title = {What is Pluto},
journal = {NASA},
note = {{https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/5-8/features/nasa-knows/what-is-pluto-58.html} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-07]}},
year = {2015},
}

@article{tt5,
author = {{European Space Agency}},
title = {L1, the first Lagrangian Point},
journal = {European Space Agency},
note = {{\url{https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/L1_the_first_Lagrangian_Point}} {[Hämtad: 2020-04-26]}},
year = {u.å},
}

@article{tt6,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {A-type main-sequence star},
journal = {Wikipedia},
note = {{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-type_main-sequence_star}} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-10]}},
year = {2020},
}

@article{tt7,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Stellar classification},
journal = {Wikipedia},
note = {{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification}} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-19]}},
year = {2020},
}

@online{youtube,
title = {Fysik 2 Avståndsmätning i rymden},
date = {2015},
organization = {Youtube},
author = {S.R. Tomas},
url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpbWQbkl8_g#t=20m15s},
}

@article{tt10,
author = {{Universe guide}},
title = {Altair (Alpha Aquilae, 53 Aquilae) Star Facts},
journal = {Universe guide},
note = {{\url{https://www.universeguide.com/star/97649/altair}} {[Hämtad: 2020-03-17]}},
year = {2020},
}
```

Comment: Werlcome to tex.sx.  It looks like your example is missing `\begin{document}`.  Ordering of the bibliography is specified by the `\bibliographystyle`.  The documentation for `IEEEtran.bst` on CTAN implies that no sorting is done.  There is an alternative, `IEEETtranS.bst`, that does say that entries are sorted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you so much for your reply. I changed \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} to \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS} but it's not 100 percent alphabetically ordered, I edited my post with a screenshot of my reference list so you can see what I mean. For example, the reference at [2] should be at [3] because "G" comes after "E" or is this ordered correctly, sorry I'm all new to latex so I'm unsure.

Comment: The list you show *is* sorted alphabetically by author's *last name*, so "G. Erik" is sorted under "Erik".  Often, such names are reversed, as "Erik, G.", but apparently this bibliography style doesn't do that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oooooh now I understand but the "G" is the author's last name not Erik. In my school it should be sorted like this, A (last name) .A (middle name, if any). Author (name), "title," etc.

Comment: And it's the first letter that is sorted so my reference list need to be sorted like this - [1] Australia Telescope National Facility "title," etc [2] C. J. Neil "title," etc [3] European Space Agency "title," etc [4] G. Erik "title," etc and so on were the first letter is important.

Comment: That's a highly unusual ordering method.  There's a package called `custom-bib` that permits one to modify the `.bst` file, but I haven't tried to use it for a very long time.  A much more direct approach, though it's a terrible hack, would be to wrap an additional set of braces around the names of human authors, to force them into an artificial strait-jacket, so they won't be manipulated in any way, but taken as a verbatim string, and sorted on that basis.

Comment: Remove the `\def\BibTeX` part and inform the template maintainer that they should do it as well. It’s useless and wrong under many respects.